# Pseudometric without triangle inequality

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, metric-spaces

I'm working on an optimization problem where I aim to minimize the total euclidean distance of the edges of a graph drawn on a fixed-size grid. For convenience, I actually use the maximum of $0$ and the euclidean distance *minus one*. Indeed, by doing this, the lower bound is $0$, independently of the number of edges. For instance, the following embedding has a cumulated “distance” of $2(\sqrt2-1)=0.8284$:

[image: grid drawing]

Obviously, it does not satisfy the conditions 2 and 4 of a metric:

1. $d(x,y) \ge 0$ (separation axiom)
2. $d(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = y$ (identity)
3. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ (symmetry)
4. $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y, z)$ (triangle inequality)

The relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Generalized_metrics) does not mention my function as a generalized metric either (it appears to be a pseudometric without the triangle inequality).

Have such functions already been studied? Under which name?

---

#### Update

Just thinking about another way to visualize the problem: increase the radius of the node to 1/2. This makes the desired distance similar to the distance between two solid objects in the physical world.

[image]

Comment: If you are using Euclidean distance minus 1 -- wouldn't condition 1 of a metric also fail?

Comment: Sorry @John Coleman, in the meantime I realized this too. My question is already edited. Anyway, I never calculate the distance between a node and itself (since there are no loops). This explains my error.

Comment: If I understand your objective function, it is the sum of the lengths of the edges minus the number of edges. If so -- I fail to see why it follows that the optimal embedding has length 0 -- though it does follow that 0 is a lower bound.

Comment: You're correct for my objective function. And yes, some optimal layouts have a length greater than 0. Thanks, I edit my question again. :(

Comment: You could probably just stipulate that the "distance" of a node to itself is zero, that way you have a symmetric, nonnegative function at least. A good level of generality might be discrete metric spaces for which q = min{d(x,y) : x \neq y } exists ("q" for "quantum" -- thinking of this as a quantum of distance) -- then your function is something like `d(x,y)-q` (unless x = y).

Comment: I think that the resulting function between points is so far from being metric-like that calling it a type of generalized metric isn't very helpful (which isn't to say that the function has no interest). Another objective function that you might consider would be the average length of the edges -- giving you 1 as a lower bound.

Comment: However, calculating the average still requires the total number of edges, isn't it? Anyway, I have updated my post with a more intuitive representation of the desired distance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42153/discussion-between-aristide-and-john-coleman).